# Upload and change a new name for image in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want, when uploading an image after that I will enter a new name for image and after press submit then the image will be changed the new name and it will be saved in path of project, please guide me how to write code ? many thanks

enter code here

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            Image Name: <input type="text" id="name"/>

            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="files" name="files">

            <input type=submit/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

code:

public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase files)
{

```
        string newFileName = "";

        if (files != null)
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/Data/images");

            bool exists = Directory.Exists(path);

            if (!exists)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            string extension = Path.GetExtension(files.FileName);
            newFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + extension;
            string filePath = Path.Combine(path, newFileName);
            files.SaveAs(filePath);

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Gemky, we're not going to guide you writing your code. You'll need to do it yourself. When you've tried something, we're happy to help you when running into problems. What have you tried, where do you run stuck, post a snippet of your code to help us guide you.

Comment: I had edit and add my code on question as above, thanks your reply

Answer (score 1):

From view pass #name value into the controller method UploadFiles along with the files in form of parameters.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase files, string newName) {

        string newFileName = "";

        if (files != null)
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/Data/images");

            bool exists = Directory.Exists(path);

            if (!exists)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            string extension = Path.GetExtension(files.FileName);
            newFileName = newName.Trim() + extension; //pass newName here
            string filePath = Path.Combine(path, newFileName);
            files.SaveAs(filePath);

        }
        return View();
    }
```

You can also add current Datetime in file name:

```
newFileName= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "-" + newName.Trim() + extension;
```

Comment: I edit your code, but it cannot get a new name image from input (text)

Comment: Can you please try searching for "How to pass values from views to controller in form of ActionResult parameters in mvc"

Comment: Dear Jimesh,
I had fixed the problem in the changing a new name for Image, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @GemkyLa Please accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem. So other's can get help from it.

Comment: Dear Jimesh: Yes, thanks. But I have a issue resize the image, it've problem on content in the image, when resize the an new image then it will don't same as image previously. it lost a part in width and height of Image. I want, when resize then it will small soom as the imge previously and the content will cannot change in image. Kindly help me, if you can do that. thanks

Comment: I can suggest you to check "ImageResizer" or "ImageBuilder" to solve your problem @GemkyLa

Comment: Dear Jimesh
I just add more code "SaveCroppedImage" about resize on my question, Please refer help me. thanks

Comment: @GemkyLa I am not able to find the problem you are facing. Is there any issue in SaveCroppedImage? Please consider the resizing problem as a separate concern(question) so that other people can help you too.

Comment: @GemkyLa Please accept the answer if your question "Upload and change a new name for image in ASP.NET MVC" is resolved so others can refer it.

Comment: Hi @GemkyLa if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.